# Camel Restlet maxThreads Component Option

Tags: rest, apache-camel, restlet

I have a problem. The apache camel documentation states that for the camel-restlet component (starting from 2.10 version) is possible to define the max number of threads that will service requests (http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html).

How can i specify this parameter?
This is the route that I made

```
from(
            "restlet:http://localhost:" + config.getEmergencyRESTPort()
                    + "?restletMethods=post,get&restletUriPatterns=#emergencyUriTemplates&maxThreads=64").process(
            new EmergencyServerProcessor(config, emergencyService));
```

I used the maxThreads parameter in the url but it doesn't work.

What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

maxThreads is not a URI option but rather it is a component option.

You can configure your restlet component by creating a bean like this:

```
<bean id="restlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
    <property name="maxThreads" value="50"/>
</bean>
```