# How to increase or configure maxThreads in apache came -restlet

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, restlet

I am working on performance testing of apache camel restlet . Now I came to know it has limit of 10 threads.

I found that we have **maxThreads** on Component level of Restlet .

I also tried [camel-restlet-maxthreads-component-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358460/camel-restlet-maxthreads-component-option), but didn't work for me.

I am using

```
    <bean id="restlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
        <property name="maxThreads" value="50"/>
    </bean>

    <restConfiguration bindingMode="off" component="restlet" scheme="http" port="8080" enableCORS="true" >

            <endpointProperty key="sslContextParameters" value="#restSSLContext"/>
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers"/>
            <corsHeaders key="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS"/>

        </restConfiguration>
```

Using :
Camel Version: 2.18.2

Please help me on how to configure maxThreads,minThreads..etc

Comment: Your questions is too open, you need to dive yourself more into and find out more. For example where do you see that 10 threads limit, and what does your Camel route do. Maybe try just to do a constant reply in your rest-dsl so its only restlet in play, and not any additional routing etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found the answer for this **maxThreads** configuration for RESTLET in camel.

you can see below code for RESTLET configuration in Camel.

```
    <bean id="restletComponent" class="org.restlet.Component" />

    <bean id="restlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletComponent">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <ref bean="restletComponent" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="maxThreads" value="20" />
        <property name="minThreads" value="1" />
        <property name="threadMaxIdleTimeMs" value="60000" />
    </bean>
```

It's perfectly working for me.

@Claus, I think we need to update this in Camel-Restlet documentation for people like me .

The one which is in Camel-restlet page didn't work for me.

Comment: Thanks I have logged a ticket to make the component configurable out of the box: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11282. For docs we are migrating from wiki to ascii doc, so the docs are what you can browse from here: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/components#components. You can do github PRs to update this docs

Comment: Thank you very much it will help others and make Camel more easy to work with.